# compile console C++ source in Linux through WSL with VS2019 problem

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I tried to compile my C++ source ( simple hello world ) on WSL Linux through VS2019 after installed g++ gdb packages in Ubuntu WSL, I could debug the code and get info on vs2019 env but when try to built it I get below error
( Maybe a manual how this remote, WSL Linux compiling work )

```
    Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

````
//#include <string>
//#include <vector>
//#include <algorithm>
//#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
inline void keep_window_open() { char c; cin >> c; }
int main()
{
    cout << "hello from ConsoleApplicationC__!\n";
    keep_window_open();
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: Can you show the source? It helps to add context.

Comment: It is simple and It run in debug mode to show stack data but on built give this error. I edit the question

Comment: Are you trying to use VS2019 on WSL? I don't think it's supposed to work. Your error message seems to be that of .NET, it probably has nothing to do with C++ or Linux.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. vs2019 has option to compile debug through WSL in windows in properties of the project. It debug but do not built. I think so.

Comment: The error you get is from visual studio, not C++ or WSL, but that is about all we can say.

Comment: @Botje I think so, any clue why vs get this error?

Comment: Once you said that you can build a project this way, I immediately tried to, but got absolutely nowhere. First VS said there were no CMake installed on the WSL machine (a lie, I checked); then it tried to install CMake on its own and simply hang there for hours with no result and no error messages of any kind. I later found out that this was caused by my VPN connection. So VS integration with WSL is not very smooth. Maybe try reinstalling something, I have no idea.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. could you just debug without built?

Comment: Huh? No you couldn't.

Comment: Tip: Don't use `inline` unless you have an extremely compelling reason. That's typically reserved for performance critical code, and a function that's called once does not benefit from inlining. Less is more. Do the simplest thing that works and optimize if and only if it's necessary.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I asked you if after vpn issue resolved and use of vs through wsl env, could you just do debug in wsl or not? Look through vs2019 g++ wsl option I could do ctrl+f5 to do a debug and it just show me some info and let me do resume until get to cin char. but when just use f5 to built I got that error! I think I have to go depth by myself. Thanks anyway for your time

Comment: @tadman I just taught It also better to use inline for just one time run func.

Comment: `inline` is almost never the answer to anything. The sad truth is 99% of courses taught in school are just plain wrong and should be almost completely ignored. Their purpose is not to teach programming so much as to see if you can survive programming.